# ¿Como remover y agregar eventos en fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Tengo un calendario que creo utilizando fullcalendar. Funciona de manera  tal que, lo primero que muestra es una ventana modal donde realizo una búsqueda en base de datos y esta me trae los datos de los usuarios, así como los eventos asociados a este. El problema radica en el momento de realizar otra búsqueda puesto que si bien me trae los datos de los usuarios no hallo la manera de reflejar en el calendario dichos eventos.

Este es el código que utilizó para crear el calendario y mostrarlo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#mostrarmodal").modal("show");

 
      $("#tra").on( "click", function() {  
          $('.paciente').toggle();
           });

   $("#fam").on( "click", function() {  
          $('.familiar').toggle();
           });      

$("#busqueda").keypress(function (e) {
            var ced_pac = $("#busqueda").val();
            if (e.which == 13) {
              $.post(base_url + "paciente/ver_cit_cal", {ced: ced_pac}, 
                  function (data){
        $('#calendario').fullCalendar({
                height: 'parent',
                header: {
                   left: 'prev, next, today, Miboton',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay'
                    
                },

                customButtons:{
                  Miboton:{
                    text:"Nueva busqueda",
                    click:function(){
                         $("#mostrarmodal").modal()
                    }
                  }
                },

                defaultDate: new Date(),
                editable: false,
                eventLimit: true, 
                  eventSources: [
                        {
                          events:$.parseJSON(data),
                          textColor: 'black'
                        }

                      ]
            });  
        }); 
                $.ajax({
                    url: base_url + 'paciente/bus_pac',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {ced: ced_pac},
                    success: function (json) {

                         if (json === "") {
                             alert(JSON.stringify(json));
                         }
                         $("#nom_pac_ver").val(JSON.stringify(json[0].pri_nom).replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
                         $("#ape_pac_ver").val(JSON.stringify(json[0].pri_ape).replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
                         $("#ced_pac_ver").val(JSON.stringify(json[0].ced_tra).replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
                         $("#age_pac_ver").val(JSON.stringify(json[0].age).replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
                      
                     }

                });
                $('#busqueda').change(function(){
                  $("#calendario").fullCalendar('removeEvents'); 
                  $("#calendario").fullCalendar('addEventSource', JSON);

                  
    });
            }
        });

     });
```

Esta parte del código me remueve los eventos anteriores perfectamente pero no me agrega los nuevos eventos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías intentar utilizar ***.destroy()*** antes de inicializar una nueva búsqueda, éste comando resetea el calendar a su estado inicial al momento de la carga.

Algo así como este flujo:

```
$('#calendario').fullCalendar('destroy');
$('#calendario').fullCalendar();
```

Lo que quiere decir es que destruyas el calendar y lo vuelvas a construir, antes de usar la nueva búsqueda.

También podrías añadir:

```
$('#calendario').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents').fullCalendar('removeEventSources');
```

Con esto le indicas que remueva todos los eventos del calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Eso es lo que hice despues de un busqueda (o cambio de seleccion)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', events);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
```

donde el object `events` contiene los datos para el calendario.

Comment: Temo que no me reconoce source me lo muestra como indefinido

Comment: Lo siento, yo pensaba en inglés.  Debe ser #calendario , y lo pone despues de 'removeEvents' como dice Hansel.